# Custom content binding for project explorer

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am using navigator content binding for customizing project explorer contents. I am getting exception on expanding a node each time saying:

```
!MESSAGE Problems occurred when invoking code from plugin:"org.eclipse.ui.navigator". 
!STACK 1 
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: No property tester contributes a property org.eclipse.core.resources.projectNature to type class <myClassName>.
```

I am not getting how to resolve this

Comment: Show us your bindings in your plugin.xml